# Jsoup select by attribute containing single quotes (Scala)

Tags: scala, jsoup

Using Jsoup with Scala, how can I select by attribute if the attribute contains single quotes? For example, `val document` contains element:

```
<a title="Select Size: 5'L x 5'W x 5'H">
```

but

```
document.select("[title*=Select Size: 5'L x 5'W x 5'H]")
```

and various combinations of triple quotes, single quotes, and backslash escaping results in

> org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Did not find balanced marker at 'title*=Select Size: 5'L x 5'W x 5'

Note that in the browser console, the following jQuery snippet successfully selects the element:

```
$("[title*='Select Size: 5\\'L x 5\\'W x 5\\'H']")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the version of Jsoup do you use?
I've just tried with 1.10.2

```
  val html = Jsoup.parse("<a title=\"Select Size: 5'L x 5'W x 5'H\">")
  print(html.select("[title*=Select Size: 5'L x 5'W x 5'H]"))
```

and got the following output

```
  <a title="Select Size: 5'L x 5'W x 5'H"></a>
```

Comment: Interesting - I'm using 1.11.2. I just copied and pasted your snippet into my repl and am still getting the same error. But your version suggestion might be the answer - it looks like 1.11.3 supports nested quotes for attribute selection (https://jsoup.org/news/release-1.11.3). I don't understand why it works for you with 1.10.2 though.

Comment: I have the same problem in Jsoup 1.14.3 :(